# tortoise svn download fails when folder size is too large

Tags: svn, xampp, tortoise-svn

I am using tortoise svn to download a project on my localhost at C:/xampp/htdocs/
The download was started, but after downloading about 95MB my it stoped and my laptop hangs and then I had to restart my laptop. The file size is about 650MB

If I download it any directory other than C it works fine.

What is reason behind this. Can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: Do you have enough free drive space available on C:?

Comment: @techie007 yes. I have 40GB free space on C

Comment: @ehp - You sure the laptop is actually hanging not trying to process a large file?  You really shouldn't put huge files into a svn repository.

Comment: @Ramhound: He's successful downloading to other locations, so any huge files shouldn't be an issue. Also, how do you know it's his own svn repo in the first place?

Comment: @ehp: Did this happen just the one time or does the laptop hang every single time you attempt to download to the C drive? Perhaps there's some file system corruption, so you should run `chkdsk /f` on the drive.

Comment: this is my clients repo. I need to work on this.

Comment: every time I tried this happened

Comment: @Karan - I don't know its general advice.  He the words he used "my localhost" and "my laptop" its a likely guess.  Of course that guess would have been wrong since its a client's repository.

Comment: some one down voted my post. Did I violate forum rules and regulations ?

Comment: @ehp: Question's fine from a rules perspective, so probably just someone who didn't like it for some reason.